# Pacman upgrade causes conflict with not present packages

Tags: node.js, archlinux, package-management, pacman-package-manager

I'm on Arco Linux(the most basic one).

I have installed the `nodejs` package with pacman.

Now when I run `sudo pacman -Su` I am getting `nodejs-lts-gallium and nodejs are in conflict. Remove nodejs? [y/N].`
But when I run `pacman -Qi nodejs-lts-gallium`, it says `error: package 'nodejs-lts-gallium' was not found`

[image]

How do I remove the `nodejs-lts-gallium` artifacts causing the conflict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that an installed package had a new dependecy to `nodejs-lts-gallium`. Or a transitive dependency does. E.g. `InstalledPackageA` now depends on `packageB` that depends on `nodejs-lts-gallium`.

You can see what would be upgraded with the following command :

```
pacman -Su --print --print-format %n
```

From that you can check what package does explicitely depend on it, with for example (edited thanks to Harm's suggestion):

```
pacman -Si $(pacman -Su --print --print-format %n) | grep -B9 nodejs-lts-gallium
```

A package should appear `Depends On [...] nodejs-lts-gallium`, that's the package which requires it.

Comment: I had the same problem as described in the question and ran a similar check. For me, the "atom" editor was the culprit.

Comment: For me it was Atom too. With eyes in tears I removed Atom ... But relying on an LTS dependency tells you everything about the current status of the application 

Comment: `pacman -Si $(pacman -Su --print --print-format %n) | grep nodejs-lts-gallium -9` helps shorten the output of the second command to the culprit. For me it was `apm`, so I ran `yay -Syu --ignore apm` to at least upgrade everything else